# How to pivot text columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table like this in my database (SQL Server 2008)

```
ID      Type            Desc
--------------------------------
C-0 Assets          No damage
C-0 Environment     No impact
C-0 People          No injury or health effect
C-0 Reputation      No impact
C-1 Assets          Slight damage
C-1 Environment     Slight environmental damage
C-1 People          First Aid Case (FAC)
C-1 Reputation      Slight impact; Compaints from local community
```

i have to display the Assets, People, Environment and Reputation as columns and display matched Desc as values. But when i run the pivot query, all my values are null.

Can somebody look into my query ans tell me where i am doing wrong?

```
Select severity_id,pt.[1] As People, [2] as Assets , [3] as Env, [4] as Rep
FROM 
(
    select * from COMM.Consequence
) As Temp
PIVOT
(
    max([DESCRIPTION]) 
    FOR [TYPE] In([1], [2], [3], [4])
) As pt
```

Here is my output

```
ID  People  Assets   Env     Rep
-----------------------------------
C-0 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C-1 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C-2 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C-3 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C-4 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C-5 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
Select severity_id, pt.People, Assets, Environment, Reputation
FROM 
(
    select * from COMM.Consequence
) As Temp
PIVOT
(
    max([DESCRIPTION]) 
    FOR [TYPE] In([People], [Assets], [Environment], [Reputation])
) As pt
```

Comment: I was curious why in the first Select pt.People was used, but the pt. prefix is not required here

Comment: What about if u don't want to show the severity_id on the result?

Comment: @SrJefers Use the query in a derived table and get the columns you want in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this in sql server and it works just fine.

I'm trying to convert this to work when one does not know what the content will be in the TYPE and DESCRIPTION columns.

I was also using this as a guide. ([Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server))

EDIT ----

Here is my solution for the above where you DON'T KNOW the content in either field....

```
-- setup commands
        drop table #mytemp
        go

        create table #mytemp (
            id varchar(10),
            Metal_01 varchar(30),
            Metal_02 varchar(100)
        )


-- insert the data
        insert into #mytemp
        select 'C-0','Metal One','Metal_One' union all
        select 'C-0','Metal & Two','Metal_Two' union all
        select 'C-1','Metal One','Metal_One' union all
        select 'C-1','Metal (Four)','Metal_Four' union all
        select 'C-2','Metal (Four)','Metal_Four' union all
        select 'C-2','Metal / Six','Metal_Six' union all
        select 'C-3','Metal Seven','Metal_Seven' union all
        select 'C-3','Metal Eight','Metal_Eight' 

-- prepare the data for rotating:
        drop table #mytemp_ReadyForRotate
        select *,
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                                mt.Metal_01,space(1),'_'
                                            ) 
                                        ,'(','_'
                                        )
                                    ,')','_'
                                    )
                                ,'/','_'
                                )
                            ,'&','_'
                            )
                    as Metal_No_Spaces
         into #mytemp_ReadyForRotate
         from #mytemp mt

    select 'This is the content of "#mytemp_ReadyForRotate"' as mynote, * from #mytemp_ReadyForRotate

-- this is for when you KNOW the content:
-- in this query I am able to put the content that has the punctuation in the cell under the appropriate column header

        Select id, pt.Metal_One, Metal_Two, Metal_Four, Metal_Six, Metal_Seven,Metal_Eight
        FROM 
        (
            select * from #mytemp
        ) As Temp
        PIVOT
        (
            max(Metal_01) 
            FOR Metal_02 In(
                                Metal_One,
                                Metal_Two,
                                Metal_Four,
                                Metal_Six,
                                Metal_Seven,
                                Metal_Eight
        )
        ) As pt


-- this is for when you DON'T KNOW the content:
-- in this query I am UNABLE to put the content that has the punctuation in the cell under the appropriate column header
-- unknown as to why it gives me so much grief - just can't get it to work like the above
-- it WORKS just fine but not with the punctuation field
        drop table ##csr_Metals_Rotated
        go

        DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @InsertIntoTempTable as nvarchar(4000)

        select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Metal_No_Spaces) 
                            from #mytemp_ReadyForRotate
                            group by Metal_No_Spaces
                            order by Metal_No_Spaces
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')

        set @query = 'SELECT id,' + @cols + ' into ##csr_Metals_Rotated from 
                     (
                        select id as id, Metal_No_Spaces 
                        from #mytemp_ReadyForRotate
                    ) x
                    pivot 
                    (
                        max(Metal_No_Spaces)
                        for Metal_No_Spaces in (' + @cols + ')
                    ) p '
        execute(@query);

        select * from ##csr_Metals_Rotated
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have to apologize - my "answer" does not answer the question.  -- I just needed the posted answer to this post to be dynamic ... where the programmer did not know the content of the fields yet sql server could create the fields on the fly and populate them.  -- I was able to figure it out and I will post my findings here in a few days - under a time crunch right now.