# Incompatible Pivot Type SQL

Tags: sql, text, pivot

I have been given a database I need to perform a **PIVOT** on. My Pivot works perfectly fine. However, one of the columns I need to perform in my SELECT is a column of **text** type. However, the PIVOT command cannot use this data type. How would I get round this?

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025934/how-to-pivot-text-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: `PIVOT` aggregates the data it shows, aggregations are forbidden on `text`. Show your code, and explain why you need to have a `text` column in a pivotted table. A workaround would be to cast the `text` to a `varchar`, but it obviously has its performance penalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal preference would be just to convert the column type to `VARCHAR(MAX)` and be done with it, `TEXT` is on the deprecation list anyway.

If this is not an option you can simply cast/convert the text value to `VARCHAR(MAX)` in your query. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (A TEXT, B CHAR(1), Val INT);
INSERT #T (A, B, Val)
VALUES ('A', '1', 1), ('A', '2', 3), ('A', '3', 2);

SELECT  pvt.A, pvt.[1], pvt.[2], pvt.[3]
FROM    #T
        PIVOT 
        (   SUM(Val)
            FOR B IN ([1], [2], [3])
        ) pvt;
```

Gives the error:

> Msg 488, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>
> Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "A" is "text", which is not comparable.

This works fine:

```
SELECT  pvt.A, pvt.[1], pvt.[2], pvt.[3]
FROM    (   SELECT A = CAST(A AS VARCHAR(MAX)), B, Val
            FROM #T
        ) t
        PIVOT 
        (   SUM(Val)
            FOR B IN ([1], [2], [3])
        ) pvt;
```